# iOS navigationController bar white space

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, frame

[image]

See the white space between the black navigation bar and the grouped table view vertical pinstripes? That space is a part of the navigation bar. If I scroll the table view, the whitespace remains in the same place.

**I need the navigationController frame to be shorter in only this viewController, so there's no whitespace as seen in the provided screenshot.**

*(Maybe it has something to do with this being a viewController with a grouped tableview)..*

Here is the only other subview for this viewController:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

This navigation bar is instantiated in the viewController in the app delegate.

I don't want what I change in this viewController to carry to the one before it (because this navigationController works with half a dozen other viewControllers just fine.)

Comment: it probably happens because you turned off all autoresize flags of the view which you'd pushed into the navigation stack. I assume otherwise it could not have been happened, and you don't see the white stripe below the `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot change the height of a navigation bar without experiencing some bizarre behavior.  Perhaps you should simply hide the navigation bar on this view controller and then implement your own view to look like a navigation bar?